# How to center Display equations on ClassicalThesis

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, koma-script, classicthesis, displaystyle

While using ClassicalThesis package with scrbook document, I noticed that the display equations defined with `\[...\]` aren't centered in the page as with scrbook without the ClassicalThesis package and its preamble. How could I restore the original behaviour by placing the display formulas centered in the page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `fleqn` option set somewhere?

Comment: Yep, it was the `fleqn` option in the ClassicalThesis-Preamble.sty (http://www.cise.ufl.edu/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis-preamble.sty)

Comment: @egreg -- since today is "answer the unanswered", make that an answer to get rid of one ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `fleqn` option; it may be either in the `\documentclass` line, or in the call to the package `amsmath` (or `mathtools`, if you load it).